# Removing a character (a specific slash) in every cell of a database field, using MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table, using MySql-PHPMyAdmin. Like how appears on the image.

[image]

My problem is there are two slashes after each `http://www.statsoft.com`. Though it's not really a problem when I run some queries on the `link` field, I can't help but notice these two slashes.
I'd like to remove one of the slashes, in each cell, with one `update` function.
How do I do that? I googled for addressing this problem, but I couldn't find a nice solution. Yet I don't really know how SQL queries deal with this.

I've tried:

```
UPDATE  `glossary`.`glossary`
  SET  `link` =  'http://www.statsoft.com//textbook/statistics-glossary/c/?button=0#Curse'
  WHERE  `glossary`.`link` =  'http://www.statsoft.com//%';
```

And of course it changed the value at every single row.
I also tried this:

```
update glossary
set link= REPLACE(link,'/','')
```

And it removed all slashes. -_-
What do I do?
Thanks.

Comment: If that is the update you used, you added the double slash back in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE glossary
SET link=REPLACE(link,'.com//','.com/')
```